# Will iCloud work with Mail and a Gmail account?

Tags: mail.app, gmail, icloud

Does iCloud  work with Mail and a Gmail account, or do I need to necessarily create a .me account and then forward the mails from gmail to .me ?

Comment: What do you mean by "does iCloud work with Mail and a Gmail account"? I'm not sure what you are exactly asking. You can set up an iCloud account with your Gmail email address and just not use the Mail portion of iCloud if you want to do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a .mac or .me account, you will use that as your iCloud email address. Otherwise, you will get a new mail account. You can either forward your gmail messages or use two different accounts (or not use iCloud for mail).

Comment: OK. Is there a way to completely sync the 2 accounts ? (gmail and apple one ?). What I mean.. to store sent messages, inbox.. everything 1-1 copy ?

Comment: @Patrick Not that I know of, sorry.

Comment: The way to do that is to have the Gmail account forward all of your mail to your iCloud email address. The iCloud email address will have a collection of everything in that case.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question to completely sync the 2 accounts, the answer is yes.  Your .me or .mac account will sync to iCloud.

Your gmail account will sync to Google's "cloud" if you enabled IMAP which automatically syncs all of your gmail.

If you have POP mail enabled for gmail, then those messages exist on your hard drive.

I use gmail via IMAP and I have 8 years of mail messages synced/stored in my gmail account.  You can check your gmail settings to see which one is enabled on your gmail account.

Answer (score -1):

A me.com iCloud.com or Mac.com are all the same. They all sync to iCloud. Then what you can do is go to your gmail account at gmail.com and go to settings/accounts and enter in some iCloud information found on https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202304 and you just enter the information in the help article to the gmail accounts page.